# Has an item been seen - React Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to update the state of an item in a JSON file (isRead) once an application has been opened. I am using react native but can not find any documentation on the subject. Is there such functions?

I am not sure whether I need to use call backs or anything like that, as it is a simple app, loading the files locally.

My Logic is like this:

```
if(isRead == false){
    Render i
}
else{
Render i++
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setState.I will show for you counter example about subject.You should review following code.

```
    import React,{Component} from "react"
    import {View,TouchableOpacity,Text} from "react-native"

    class Test extends Component{
      state ={
           count = 0
      }
    changeCount(){
       this.setState({count:this.state.count++})
    }

    render(){
       return(
             <View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.changeCount.bind(this)}/>
                <Text>{this.state.count}</Text>
            <View/>)
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I also found this [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html) very useful as well.